# Как раскидать строки из одного файла по нескольким согласно условию?

Tags: shell

есть файл содержащий строки:

```
фильмы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
фильмы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
фильмы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
музыка и клипы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
музыка и клипы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
музыка и клипы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
книги, журналы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
книги, журналы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
книги, журналы|разный текст|еще какойто текст|какие то цифры
и тд.
```

нужно взять все строки содержащие "фильмы" в первом столбце и сохранить в файл "фильмы.txt"
далее взять все строки содержащие "музыка и клипы" в первом столбце и сохранить в файл "музыка и клипы.txt"
далее взять все строки содержащие "книги, журналы" в первом столбце и сохранить в файл "книги, журналы.txt"
и тд. со всеми сотнями тысяч строк

строки попадающие под одну категорию могут идти не по порядку

Comment: Ваш вариант не подходит?

Comment: Принципиально нужно сделать именно консольными командами? Python/R/любой скриптовый язык не подходят?

Comment: @Человексинтернета, а вообще здесь принято задавать вопросы, а не раздавать задания бесплатным фрилансерам. пожалуйста, не нарушайте в дальнейшем принятых на этом сайте правил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

примерно так:

```
$ cut -d '|' -f 1 файл | sort -u | while read p; do grep "^$p[[:space:]]*|" файл > "$p.txt"; done
```

- `cut -d '|' -f 1 файл` — извлечь первое поле из строк `файла`
- `sort -u` — отсортировать список и убрать дубликаты
- `while read p; do ...; done` — выполнить набор инструкций для каждой из строк (содержимое строки — в переменной `$p`)
- `grep "^$p[[:space:]]*|" файл` — выбрать из `файла` строки, начинающиеся с искомой строки
- `> "$p.txt` — и записать их в файл с указанным именем.